# How to *lower* Wifi transmitted power on AR9331 under OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt, wifi

I am trying to *lower* the transmitted Wifi power on a router running OpenWRT.

I've tried using the `iw` command to set the `txpower` to a very low 100 (1dBm)...

```
root@GL-iNet:~# iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed 100
```

...and `iwinfo seems to report that the command was executed correctly...

```
root@GL-iNet:~# iwinfo
wlan0     ESSID: "Moonphase WAP"
          Access Point: E4:95:6E:40:39:8C
          Mode: Master  Channel: 1 (2.412 GHz)
          Tx-Power: 1 dBm  Link Quality: unknown/70
          Signal: unknown  Noise: -92 dBm
          Bit Rate: unknown
          Encryption: none
          Type: nl80211  HW Mode(s): 802.11bgn
          Hardware: unknown [Generic MAC80211]
          TX power offset: unknown
          Frequency offset: unknown
          Supports VAPs: yes  PHY name: phy0
```

...but the actual emitted power does not seem to change no matter what I set the `txpower` to.

I've also tried...

- using `iw` on the `phy` rather than the `dev`
- setting the `txpower` in the `/etc/config/wireless` and `reboot`ing
- downing/upping the interfaces

...and none seem to have any effect on actual output power.

## How can I pro grammatically lower the output power?

Notes:

I am aware of all the driver limitations in `regulatory.bin`, but I do not think these should matter here since I am trying to set a `txpower` that is *lower* than the county specific limits.

This router is a a clone of a TP-LINK TL-703N.

[image]

The router is running OpenWRT...

```
root@GL-iNet:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.49 (alzhao@alzhao-ubuntu) (gcc version 4.8.3 (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04 r42801) ) #6 Thu Oct 9 18:20:47 HKT 2014
```

The Wifi is handed by an AR9331 chip.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the command...

```
iw wlan0 set txpower fixed 1
```

...does seem to set the radio to 1dBm, it is just even at this low level every client I have still shows 5 bars when in the same room. I had to take the receivers 30 feet away and on the other side of a wall for the lower signal strength to be visible.

Debugging this problem was compounded by the fact that the syntax for setting the power level inside `/etc/config/wireless` is different from the imperative form, so this is the format for setting it to 1dBm in the `wifi-defvice` section of the config file...

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option txpower '1'
```

Comment: Okay I did the same thing as you suggested but this doesn't seem to reduce the transmitted wifi power.

Comment: my Wifi router is : TP-Link TL-MR3020
can you suggest what can be the issue??